# What are the privileges and the configuration required for SQL Producer

Tags: codefluent

From the documentation I couldn't find anything related to privilege settings and configurations required for SQLServer Producer.

What should be the grants and privileges given to SQL user in order to have CodeFluent Entities to generate all the objets (table, procedures and so on)?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the model, the SQL user needs to have the `serveradmin` server role (or above: `sysadmin`). This server role is needed to run the *project_runtime.sql* script (`sp_addmessage`).

The rest of the scripts are DELETE, ALTER, UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT. You can view the SQL roles here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189612.aspx

If you need to setup specific restrictions, you could run the *project_runtime.sql* manually (with a high server role), and let the user do the rest.

Also, you can configure the SQL Producer to not generate the `sp_addmessage`, because it's not mandatory to run the application. Set `Add Runtime Messages=False`

[image: SQL Server producer configuration]

Regards,